# do we use string args only in main method?

Tags: java

why can't we use string args this way?
Here I have used String args[] in the readAttributes method to read input outside the main function.This shows a compilation error.I wanted to pass the parameters through keyword from a different method(readAttributes) other than main using String args.What changes are required?

```
 class rectangle
{
     int l,b;
    public void area_rect(int l,int b)
    {

        System.out.print(+(l*b));
    }
    public void perimeter_rect(int l,int b)
    {

        System.out.print(+(2*(l+b)));
    }


    ***public void readAtrributes(String args[])
        {

            int l=Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            int b=Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

        }***



}
public class rec
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        readAttributes ra=new readAttributes();

        area_rect ar=new area_rect();
        perimeter_rect pr=new perimeter_rect();


    }
}
```

Comment: You get the error because you try to use a method as a class, not because of the method. This is not a problem with `String[]` as parameter, but basic java-language. Read a tutorial

Comment: `readAtrributes()`, `area_rect()`, `perimeter_rect()` are method. not a class. you cannot create a object using a method(breaking java principles). first you have to create a object using a class, then you can call 'readAtrributes()' method.

Answer (score 0):

readAttributes is a method, yet you try to initialize it as a class.

Even if it were, you would still have to pass an actual String array as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

In Java args contains the supplied [command-line arguments](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html) as an array of String objects.

In other words, if you run your program as `java Program` one two then args will contain `["one", "two"]`.

Answer (score 0):

`readAttributes` is a method and you created an object from it so you get compilation error

you must call those methods in this way

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    // creating an object from class rectangle
    rectangle rect = new rectangle();

    // calling methods of that object 
    rect.readAtrributes(args);
    rect.area_rect(12, 12);
    rect.perimeter_rect(10, 12);

}
```